# calculate lat long of a particular location at a given distance and angle from my current location

Tags: math, location

I know my current GPS location(lat,long). I want to know the (lat,long) of a location that is at a distance(d) from my current location and at a particular angle.

Can someone provide me an exact formula to calculate target(lat,lon) which includes my location(lat,lon),distance d and angle r.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `r=0` is north, `r=pi/2` is east that `R` is the earth radius and that `d` is much smaller than `R`, then you should have:

```
lon_1 = lon_0 + d*sin(r)/(R*cos(lat_0));
lat_1 = lat_0 + d*cos(r)/R;
```